# How to get switch() to handle NA?

Tags: r, sapply

Okay, I have to recode a df, because I want factors as integers:

```
library(dplyr)

load(url('http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/crash2.rda'))

df <- crash2 %>% select(source, sex)

df$source <- sapply(df$source, switch, "telephone" = 1, "telephone entered manually" = 2, "electronic CRF by email" = 3, "paper CRF enteredd in electronic CRF" = 4, "electronic CRF" = 5, NA)
```

This works as intended, but there are NAs in the next variable (sex) and things get complicated:

```
df$sex <- sapply(df$sex, switch, "male" = 1, "female" = 2, NA)
```

returns a list with NAs switched to oblivion. Use `unlist()` returns a vector that is too short for the df.

```
length(unlist(sapply(df$sex, switch, "male" = 1, "female" = 2, NA)))
```

should be `20207`, but is `20206`.

What I want is a vector matching the df by returning NAs as NAs.

Besides a working solution I would be extra thankful for an explanation where I went wrong and how the code actually works.

**Edit:** Thank you for all your answers. As is so often the case, there is an even more efficent solution I should have noticed myself (well, I noticed it by myself, but too late, obviously):

```
>str(df$sex)
Factor w/ 2 levels "male","female": 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

So I can just use `as.numeric()` to get what I want.

Comment: probably no need for loops or switch; try `x = c("a", "e", "a", "a", NA, "d", "b", "b", NA, "d"); lu = c( "a"=1, "b"=2, "c"=3, "d"=4, "e"=5); lu[x]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interested, there's also a `dplyr` way of doing this with `case_when()`:

```
load(url('http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/crash2.rda'))

df <- crash2 %>% dplyr::select(source, sex) %>% 
  mutate(source = case_when(
    source == "telephone"~1, 
    source == "telephone entered manually"~2, 
    source == "electronic CRF by email"~3, 
    source == "paper CRF enteredd in electronic CRF"~4, 
    source == "electronic CRF"~5), 
    sex = case_when(
      sex == "male" ~ 1, 
      sex == "female" ~ 2))

table(df$sex, useNA="ifany")
#     1     2  <NA> 
# 16935  3271     1
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use `` `NA` ``.

```
x
# [1] "a" "e" "a" "a" NA  "d" "b" "b" NA  "d"
unname(sapply(x, switch, "a"=1, "b"=2, "c"=3, "d"=4, "e"=5, `NA`=NA))
# [1]  1  5  1  1 NA  4  2  2 NA  4
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c("a", "e", "a", "a", NA, "d", "b", "b", NA, "d")
```

Comment: what is `` `NA` `` doing ?

Comment: @YOLO You may also write `"NA"` (not if you have `"NA"` as character in `x`, though), it identifies `NA` as another level (like a character `"NA"`) and `"NA"=NA` assigns `NA` to it.

Comment: `switch(NA_character_, `NA`= 1)` is `1` , while `switch(NA, `NA`= 1)` is `NULL`, because the first argument is not coerced to character but to integer, really not what I expected.